# AMOLED display vs. LCD display: Power consumption when displaying white only?

Tags: lcd, display, smartphones, amoled

LCD's power consumption **only depends on the screen brightness** setting, not on the displayed content, unlike AMOLED, where brighter **colours** (towards white) cause more power consumption, while black means that the pixel is completely turned off (=no power consumption).

Now, what consumes more power at **the same brightness?**

- LCD?
- AMOLED displaying white?

Comment: The LCD still needs the backlight, which consumes a not-insignificant amount of power.

Comment: In addition, the LCD has two polarizing filters which remove a significant portion of the light. It also depends on the absolute efficiencies of the AMOLED's vs. LED's. See https://www.anandtech.com/show/9394/analysing-amoled-power-efficiency

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Just like white pixels on AMOLED.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik AMOLED has polarizing filters as well - to reduce reflections. Thanks for the link, very interesting!